# Duplicating this CSS formatting

Tags: css

It seems I need AngularJS for this code but I'm hoping someone with CSS skills could duplicate this easily.

I am trying to duplicate this on another site that is just an HTML page.

It is on this site:  http://sarasparodandgun.org/pages/saraspa

It is the heading, "SARASPA HOME" with the "gradient" grey afterwards.  The grey is responsive.  I've tried using the `title`, and `decoration` css but it doesn't line up properly for me.  I'm sure it has something to do with the `block-header`, `ng-scope` and `ng-binding` but I can't see it on firebug.

```
<div class="block-header ng-scope">
  <h2>
    <span class="title ng-binding"> SaraSpa Home </span>
    <span class="decoration"></span>
    <span class="decoration"></span>
    <span class="decoration"></span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: in chrome you can right hand click on each bit and press inspect, from here you can see all the css that applies to that area.

Comment: Why would you need Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gray background is on the h2. The white dashes through the gray are the decoration spans.

There is nothing in the styling that requires Angular

here are the relevant rules:

```
.block-header h2 {
  background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #515151;
  font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 40px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.block-header h2 .title {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.block-header h2 .decoration {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

here's a fiddle of the effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/yjnu3ypz/

Comment: I would like to add, for my situation since it was in a Wordpress theme and other classes were acting on the css, I had to adjust the:  `h2 { padding-bottom: 0px; }` and `margin: 0px 0;`  I know I didn't specify that in my post but I didn't think ahead that I would run into surrounding `<div>`s